# What is the time complexity of std::sort() in the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity

What is the complexity of `std::sort()` in the C++ Standard Library? Which sort is applied? Is there any rule of applying any particular sorting algorithm there?

Answer (score 45):

Before C++11:

`std::sort` must have average case linearithmic (n log n) time complexity.  Any algorithm may be used so long as that time complexity requirement is met.  There is no worst case time complexity requirement.

If you want a guaranteed worst case time complexity function, use `std::stable_sort`, which has quasilinear worst case time complexity (n log^2 n).

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the word "linearithmic" -- hadn't come across it before, but it's definitely a keeper :)

Comment: I don't know about C++03, but C++0x draft claims O(n log n) **worst case** complexity. And `std::stable_sort` is guaranteed to run in O(n log^2 n).

Comment: @ybungalobill:  So it does.  C++03 explicitly states that there is no worst-case complexity requirement.  I wasn't aware that changes were made to the C++0x algorithm complexities in C++0x.  (You're right about `partial_sort`; it only has quasilinear time complexity in both C++03 and C++0x).

Answer (score 17):

### The standard guarantees

From the C++11/14 standard, `std::sort` is guaranteed to have:

> **§25.4.1.1/3**
>
> Complexity: `O(N log(N))` (where `N == last - first`) comparisons.

The other, stable, standard sorting algorithm (namely `std::stable_sort`) is guaranteed to have:

> **25.4.1.2/3**
>
> Complexity: It does at most `N log²(N)` (where `N == last - first`) comparisons; if enough extra memory is available, it is `N log(N)`.

For `std::forward_list::stable`, instead:

> **23.3.4.6/26**
>
> Complexity: Approximately `N log(N)` comparisons, where `N` is `distance(begin(), end())`.

The same goes for `std::list`:

> **23.3.5.5/31**
>
> Complexity: Approximately `N log(N)` comparisons, where `N == size()`.

### Sorting algorithm

The C++ standard does not specify which sorting algorithm to apply in any of the above cases. This would be oftentimes and unnecessary implementation restriction.

If you need to know you might have luck looking in a specific compiler specification. For example for GNU GCC you would start [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a01027.html).

Comment: So the worse complexity of `std::sort()` is also `O(NlogN)`?

Answer (score 7):

The complexity is `O(n log n)`. Some common implementations use introsort as far as I know:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort

Comment: just read about introsort, pretty cool.  reminded me of a sort with someone's first name in it, but i cant find it.  nicksort, petesort, something like that.  does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: @jon_darkstar: You may be thinking of Timsort. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Answer (score 5):

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(C%2B%2B)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28C%2B%2B%29)

> The specific sorting algorithm is not mandated and may vary across implementations. The GNU Standard C++ library, for example, uses a hybrid sorting algorithm: introsort is performed first, to a maximum depth given by 2×log2 n, where n is the number of elements, followed by an insertion sort on the result.[1] Whatever the implementation, the complexity should be O(n log n) comparisons on the average. [2]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `std::sort()`:

This is from C++03 standard, section 25.3. The performance guarantee:

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator>
void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);

template<class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare> void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
    Compare comp);
```

> 1 Effects: Sorts the elements in the range [first, last).
>
> 2 Complexity: Approximately N log N (where N == last - first) comparisons on the average.

Comment: @James, sorry, copied the full snippet. `last` and `first` are the iterators passed to `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

The [C++ standard specifies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) that the [worst-case runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case) of `std::sort()` is in `O(n log n)` - where `n` is number of sorted elements (cf. C++11, Section 25.4.1.1).

The standard doesn't specify a particular sorting algorithm.

Thus, a conforming `std::sort()` implementation is free to choose any algorithm that satisfies the above runtime requirement.

Note that C++ standard revisions before C++11 [just required that the *average* runtime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) of `std::sort()` is in `O(n log n)`.

See also the stackoverflow question [What algorithms are used in C++11 std::sort in different STL implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22339240/427158)  to get an idea what actual sorting algorithms are used in real-world STL implementations.

Answer (score 0):

On average, linearithmic in the distance between first and last: Performs approximately **N*log2(N)** (where N is this distance) comparisons of elements, and up to that many element swaps (or moves).