# C++ compare two sentences

Tags: c++, algorithm

randomly came across this:

Develop an algorithm to compare two sentences to see if
they match or not. The key aspect of these sentences is that
the words could be in any order (e.g. "california is hot" and "
hot is california" are two sentences that would match).

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Parse each sentence into words, use space as delimiters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683302/how-to-split-a-space-separated-string-into-multiple-strings-in-c)
2. Add all `std::string` words to a `std::vector<std::string>`, then `sort`.
3. Use the [`==`operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp) to compare the two `vector`s for equality.

Comment: Is there a language-independent way to do this?

Comment: @templateboy I just described a relatively agnostic way to do this, the implementation will be based on the available classes and libraries in the language of interest.

Comment: 1. are you saying == operator will ignore the order of the words? 2. if we were to use vector sort, what would be the complexity?

Comment: 1. For two `vector`s to compare equally, they have to have the same elements *in the same order*, hence the sorted requirement. 2. The standards specifies `sort` of `vector` must have [O(n log n) complexity or faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484900/what-is-the-complexity-of-the-sort-function-in-the-c-standard-library)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps put words into a `std::map<string, int>` and count up the element each time you find a word on the one side, and down on the other side, then iterate over the map and check that all entries are zero. [This assumes that "california is hot hot" isn't supposed to be the same as "hot is california", in which case you need a bit more logic, to only count words the first time you see them on each side]

Or put each word in each sentence into a `std::vector<string>`, then sort each vector and compare the two vectors. Again, strategy changes if the sentence needs to be recognised regardless of the number of times each word is seen.

Comment: In theory, you only need one sorted vector (and N lookups à logN complexity), but that might be slower (quicksort is quite cache-friendly AFAIK).

Comment: And much easier to write `if (vector1 == vector2) ...` than to check every element. And unless we're compared the Quran with the Bible or some such, it's probably not going to tax a modern computer... ;)

Comment: Using an `unordered_map<string, int>` is of course asymptotically faster, in theory. Whether or not it's faster in practice had to be measured.

Comment: Again, probably not measurable for human entered text... ;)

Comment: *"And much easier to write `if (vector1 == vector2)` ... than to check every element"* well, it's not *that* hard IMHO http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ea37378d4d0ae51

Comment: That does assume that "california is hot hot" is the same as "hot is california" - which is not clear from the OP. My solution will need tweaking for the case where that is the desired result.