# Check std::vector has duplicates

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, vector, duplicates

I want to check if a vector of integers has any duplicates or not, and have to return true if it does. So I try to do something like this:

```
vector<int> uGuess = {1,2,3,3,4,5}
vector<int> a = uGuess;
sort(a.begin(), a.end());
bool d = unique(a.begin(), a.end());
```

And this will not work since unqiue cannot be assigned as a bool value.
How should I proceed towards this?
If I were to write a for loop to perform the same action, how should I do that?

Comment: `unique` doesn't do what you are describing you want to do

Comment: `auto it = std::unique(a.begin(), a.end()); bool b = it == a.end();`

Comment: Check a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: @Jarod42 doesn't work on non-sorted vectors

Comment: @patatahooligan: In the example it is sorted as initialized, then it gets sorted. I think it's safe to say it's sorted.

Comment: @FredLarson True, but OP's statement of the problem does not mention that the array is sorted. OP should clarify.

Comment: @patatahooligan It doesn't matter, he calls `sort()` in his code, so then it's sorted.

Comment: I kid you not, I somehow skipped over that line before. In that case @Jarod42 's comment could be the accepted answer.

Comment: "How should I proceed towards this" depends on what **this** is. Don't post code that doesn't work and ask people to guess at what it's intended to do; **say it**. What should the value in `d` mean?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of [Determining if an unordered vector<T> has all unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769174/determining-if-an-unordered-vectort-has-all-unique-elements) and [Determine if there are duplicates in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252730/determine-if-there-are-duplicates-in-vector).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking at google for `std::unique` I found this page [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). I looked at what it did:

> Eliminates all except the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range [first, last)

So it looks like it does what you want - removes the duplicates.

I then looked at what it returns...

> ... returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range

So the result from `std::unique` is a sequence which is not necessary the same as the whole `vector`.

If nothing was removed, the return value would be the end of the `vector`.

So you want:

```
vector<int>::iterator it = std::unique(a.begin(), a.end());
bool wasUnique = (it == a.end());
```

Or for C++11:

```
auto it = std::unique(a.begin(), a.end());
bool wasUnique = (it == a.end());
```

Finally for the unique function to work, the `vector` needs to be sorted, so the complete code would be:

```
sort(a.begin(), a.end());
auto it = std::unique(a.begin(), a.end());
bool wasUnique = (it == a.end());
```

Comment: _"So it looks like it does what you want - removes the duplicates."_ What?! Where in the world does the OP ask for removing duplicates? This answer is wrong as `std::unique` modifies the vector.

Comment: @Zakk Modifying a *duplicate vector* seems fine – QA tried that her-/himself, too, but didn't manage to apply the correct checks afterwards...

Comment: @Aconcagua My comment was about removing the duplicates. That was not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Zakk Not directly – but the initial idea has been since right from the start removing duplicates from a copy and then compare sizes – if differing, removal took place thus duplicates are still available in original unchanged vector – solely the appropriate test for removal detection has been lacking...

Answer (score 33):

The algorithm you're looking for is [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

```
// The container must be sorted!
const std::vector<int> sortedVector = {1,2,3,3,4,5};
const bool hasDuplicates = std::adjacent_find(sortedVector.begin(), sortedVector.end()) != sortedVector.end();
```

Unlike `std::unique`, `std::adjacent_find` doesn't modify the container.

As a bonus, `std::adjacent_find` returns an iterator to the first element in the duplicate "pair":

```
const auto duplicate = std::adjacent_find(sortedVector.begin(), sortedVector.end());

if (duplicate != sortedVector.end())
    std::cout << "Duplicate element = " << *duplicate << "\n";
```

Comment: Only works for sorted containers

Answer (score 21):

You should using set

```
set<int> s(a.begin(), a.end());
return s.size() != a.size();
```

Comment: You mean `return s.size()==a.size();`, right? I like this approach because I do something similar in python, but do you have any idea how fast this is vs sorting?

Comment: @snooze_bear This should be as fast as sorting but if you use `std::unordered_set` in place of `std::set` it can be faster as it is a hash set.

Comment: why does it not have O(n) complexity where n = a.size() ?

Comment: @ShubhamGarg Late reply for late readers: Insertion complexity for `std::set` is `O(log(s))` with `s` being current size of the set – there are `n` elements, and `O(sum(i = 0 -> n) { log(i) })` (is that understandable?) remains `O(n*log(n))`...

Answer (score 4):

If someone is forced to write own algorithm:

```
bool hasDuplicates(const std::vector<int>& arr) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); ++j) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But in real code you should use things that already exist, and in the standard library.

Comment: That leaves the question: what function in the STL is the best fit for this problem?

Comment: I believe this will have bad performance for large vectors due to caches. If you use `for (std::size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j)` you test the small ranges first, which fits in cache, and only at the end do slow searches outside of cache. It's likely to terminate early if there is a duplicate and never reach the slow part.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the vector if it's not already sorted, and then use [`std::unique()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/), like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {3, 1, 3, 4, 5};
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto it = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << ((it == v.end()) ? "Unique\n" : "Duplicate(s)\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Duplicate(s)

Comment: Here, the original vector gets changed. So, this can't be the useful method.

Comment: @gsamaras The input vector has to be sorted. Am I right?

Comment: Yes the vector needs to be sorted, answer updated! Thanks @John for the comment and the upvote!

Answer (score 2):

So far all these solutions either modify the container or have O(n²) complexity. You can put a std::map to much better use:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

template <typename Iterator>
bool has_duplicates( Iterator first, Iterator last )
{
  std::map <typename std::iterator_traits <Iterator> ::value_type, std::size_t> histogram;

  while (first != last)
    if (++histogram[ *first++ ] > 1) 
      return true;

  return false;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  using std::begin;
  using std::end;

  int a[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
  int b[] = { 2, 3, 5, 5, 7 };

  std::vector <int> c( begin(a), end(a) );
  std::vector <int> d( begin(b), end(b) );

  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "a has duplicates false : " << has_duplicates( begin(a), end(a) ) << "\n";
  std::cout << "b has duplicates true  : " << has_duplicates( begin(b), end(b) ) << "\n";
  std::cout << "c has duplicates false : " << has_duplicates( begin(c), end(c) ) << "\n";
  std::cout << "d has duplicates true  : " << has_duplicates( begin(d), end(d) ) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It will use more memory and not be faster than sorting a vector.

Comment: Yes, but sorting a vector _modifies_ the original content.

Comment: Of course. Look, I don’t think you understand the algorithm here and/or have completely ignored its termination conditions. For a large vector of completely unique elements, the memory requirements are not quite as friendly, but there is a trade-off _entirely dependent on OP’s data and his operating requirements_. Why not give OP all the options instead of blindly clunking along ‘sort a copy and write your own test’ for a very-likely minor memory issue when you could be using the power of the Standard Library to efficiently histogram for you?

Comment: Then you should have specified in the answer that this solution is only good if the number of unique elements is relatively small (or less probabilistically, if a duplicate is close to the beginning of the array).

Comment: No, it is only _bad_ if the source data is particularly large _and_ unlikely to have any duplicates. Please quit making unprovable generalized statements about probability and requirements. (If your data set is more likely to have a duplicate near the end, then reverse-walk your source, LOL.)

Answer (score 1):

If your vector is small, say < 32 objects, or if copying and sorting the objects is expensive or impossible due to lack of move or copy constructor/assignment then a straight `O(n^2)` compare everything against everything else algorithm is the way to go.

Here is my solution:

```
template <typename Iterator>
bool has_duplicates( Iterator first, Iterator end ) {
    for (auto i = first; i != end; ++i) {
        for (auto j = first; i != j; ++j) {
            if (*i == *j) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename Container>
bool has_duplicates(const Container &v) {
    for (const auto & i : v) {
        for (const auto & j : v) {
            if (&i == &j) break;
            if (i == j) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a more complex vector and want to know which value is duplicated, you can do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

template <typename InputContainer_t, typename GetCompareValueLambda_t>
bool HasDuplicates(const InputContainer_t& container, GetCompareValueLambda_t compare)
{
    using CompareValue_t = decltype(compare(*container.begin()));
    std::unordered_set<CompareValue_t> setUniqueValues;
    bool hasDuplicates = false;

    for (const auto & element : container)
    {
        CompareValue_t compareValue = compare(element);

        auto [_, successful] = setUniqueValues.insert(compareValue);

        if (!successful)
        {
            printf("Value '%s' is not unique.\n", std::to_string(compareValue).c_str());
            hasDuplicates = true;
        }
    }
    return hasDuplicates;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a {1,2,2};
    HasDuplicates(a, [](auto x){ return x; });
    
    std::vector<S> b {{1, 0},{2, 1}, {2, 0}};
    HasDuplicates(b, [](auto x){ return x.idx; });

    return 0;
}
```

see also: https://onlinegdb.com/bvOzbptnR