# Determine if there are duplicates in vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, unique

I would like to determine if there are duplicates in a vector. What is the best option here?

```
sort(arrLinkToClients.begin(), arrLinkToClients.end(), [&](const type1& lhs,const type1& rhs)
{
    lhs.nTypeOfLink < rhs.nTypeOfLink;
});

auto it = unique(arrLinkToClients.begin(), arrLinkToClients.end(), [&](const type1& lhs, const type1& rhs)
{
    lhs.nTypeOfLink == rhs.nTypeOfLink;
});

//how to check the iterator if there are duplicates ?
if (it)
{
  //
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for duplicates in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860634/checking-for-duplicates-in-a-vector)

Comment: what is `std::unique` doing and what does it return?

Comment: If the question is only "are there **any** duplicates", `std::unique` is overkill, since it removes **all** duplicates. That's why you're getting answers that suggest `std::adjacent_find`, which returns when it finds the first duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining if an unordered vector<T> has all unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769174/determining-if-an-unordered-vectort-has-all-unique-elements). Note that the question @UdayrajDeshmukh linked is marked as a duplicate of the question I link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "best" option does not exist. It depends on how you define "best".

Here are some solutions, each with their own advantages and disadvantages:

**`Using map`**

```
template <class T>
auto has_duplicates(const std::vector<T>& v) -> bool
{
    std::unordered_map<T, int> m;

    for (const auto& e : v)
    {
        ++m[e];

        if (m[e] > 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**`Using set`**

```
template <class T>
auto has_duplicates(const std::vector<T>& v) -> bool
{
    std::unordered_set<int> s;
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter(s, s.begin());
   
    return v.size() != s.size();
}
```

**`Using sort and adjacent_find (mutating range)`**

```
template <class T>
auto has_duplicates(std::vector<T>& v) -> bool
{
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    return std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end()) != v.last();
}
```

**`Manual iteration with std::find`**

```
template <class T>
auto has_duplicates(const std::vector<T>& v) -> bool
{
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        if (std::find(it + 1, v.end(), *it) != v.end())
            return true;
            
    return false;
}
```

**`Manual iteration`**

```
template <class T>
auto has_duplicates(const std::vector<T>& v) -> bool
{
    for (auto i1 = v.begin(); i1 != v.end(); ++i1)
        for (auto i2 = i1 + 1; i2 != v.end(); ++i2)
            if (*i1 == *i2)
                return true;
    
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicates, the iterator returned from `unique` is the end iterator. So:

```
if (it != arrLinkToClients.end())
    cout << "Some duplicates found!";
```

Comment: The return value is a forward iterator to the new end of the range, so you cannot do this.

Comment: @0xBADF00 -- the iterator returned by `std::unique` has the same type as the iterators that the function was called with. There's nothing wrong with this comparison.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok my bad, ofcourse you can do that, but it will not accomplish what the OP wanted.

Comment: @0xBADF00 — it looks okay to me. Why do you say that it won’t work?

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok I am obviously stupid it works great (did not think of the sort)