# C++/STL which algorithm should I use to check if a container has duplicates?

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any STL algorithm that would tell if a container has duplicated elements (using the `operator==` or a given predicate)?

Let's consider those two vectors:

```
std::vector<int> v1{ 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> v2{ 1, 2, 1 };
```

I would expect a function like that:

```
std::is_exclusive( v1.begin(), v1.end() ); // returning true
std::is_exclusive( v2.begin(), v2.end() ); // returning false
```

Is there such a simple function? I could not find any (found `std::unique`, but this modifies the vector...)

Note: I'm not asking how to "check if a container has duplicates", I know how I can do that (basically, I can do `( std::set<int>( v1.begin(), v1.end() ).size() == v1.size() )` and there may exist many other options. I'm asking if there is a STL algorithm function that would do it in a smarter way because I'm surprised I could not find any...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769174/determining-if-an-unordered-vectort-has-all-unique-elements

Comment: @EdgarRokjān: I suppose this means the answer is "No there isn't"...;-)

Comment: Such a function would be O(n^2), that's probably why there is none.

Comment: @alain Do you mean naive implementation? For with additional hashset it runs in average O(N), with O(N) space.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That is one option, not the best in time but the best in space, albeit destructive.

Comment: @jpo38 yes, precisely :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining if an unordered vector<T> has all unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769174/determining-if-an-unordered-vectort-has-all-unique-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STL is about efficiency and universality. There seems to be no universal and efficient way to check if a container has duplicates without modifying it. Hence, no wonder that no such algorithm exists in STL.

Comment: Err, `unordered_set` would work fine in most cases and gives average O(n) complexity (requires hash and equality comparison, and possibly copy c'tor). Another possibility with worst case O(n log n) complexity, for forward iterator ranges, is to make a vector of iterators or pointers and sort these (requires less-than-comparable type). A generic solution has to allocate O(N) additional memory, though, and impose certain constraints on types, which is the more likely reason there is no such algorithm yet.

Answer (score 4):

One way of implementing your STL-like `is_exclusive` template function would be by using a `std::unordered_map` which keeps the counting of the elements in the range. The function template could return `false` as soon as the count for any element is over one:

```
#include <unordered_map>

template<typename ForwardIt>
bool is_exclusive(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last) {
    std::unordered_map<typename ForwardIt::value_type, unsigned> count;

    for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it)
        if (++count[*it] > 1)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

For your example:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> v2{ 1, 2, 1 };


    assert(is_exclusive(v1.begin(), v1.end()));
    assert(!is_exclusive(v2.begin(), v2.end()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can thing is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find, but it requires that the elements are sorted as it will check in the adjacent element.

EDIT:

There is no stl algorithm that can do that as you ask, the other alternative is use std::any_of.

Comment: I'm not asking how to "check if a container has duplicates"....there's many ways to do that (using adjacent_find is one of them). I'm looking for a function taking two iterators and returning true/false....

Comment: Then I will say there are any like you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to use std::set.

Copy your vector into the set and compare if the number of elements are the same.

If yes you have no duplicate, if no you can guess the number of duplicates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
int has_duplicate(const std::vector<int> & v)
{
    std::set<int> s(v.begin(), v.end());
    return v.size() - s.size();
}

int
main()
{

    std::vector<int> v1{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> v2{ 1, 2, 1 };
    std::cout << has_duplicate(v1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_duplicate(v2) << std::endl;
}
```

for v1 the output is 0 -> you have no duplicate
for v2 the output is 1 -> you have one duplicate

The algorithm costs O(N*log(N))

Comment: You could simplify by passing the iterators directly into the constructor of the set.

Comment: That's what I said in the "Note" of my question.